# Adjusting highcharter plot dimensions in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I am using highcharter plots in Rmarkdown and I can't seem to adjust the height or the width (in RStudio). Any suggestions? Details below:

If I use the basic default code;

````
```{r}
library(highcharter)

cars %>%
  hchart(.,"scatter",hcaes(x=speed,y=dist))
```
````

I get this:

[image]

That doesn't change if I edit chunk options `fig.height=4,fig.width=8` or if I change dimensions in the plot `hc_chart(height=800,width=600)`.

If I save the plot and print using a taglist, then it starts to become usable.

````
```{r}
h <- cars %>%
  hchart(.,"scatter",hcaes(x=speed,y=dist))

htmltools::tagList(list(h))
```
````

[image]

But, I still can't adjust dimensions using chunk options or using internal plot dimensions.

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
highcharter_0.5.0
```

Comment: Did you try rendering? For me the dimension seems right.

Comment: Hmm. you are right. The default script seems to plot fine when directly knitting the doc. And changing the height through `hc_chart(height=800)` does seem to work. But with new height, the plot overlaps with lower elements.

Comment: Try to use `hc_size`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `hc_size` with `height` and `width` arguments:

```
{r}
h <- cars %>%
  hchart(.,"scatter",hcaes(x=speed,y=dist)) %>%
  hc_size(height=800,width=600)
h
```

Had the same problem and the comment from @jbkunst (kudos to them) to your question led me to this solution and it works - so I thought I'd post it as an answer.